# How do I suppose to fetch data from a specific room in Twilio?

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-api

**Hello Awesome People!**

Get stuck while trying to configure a Video Chat with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource) and Django

I want to fetch data from a room, I realize that only the `unique_name` is present:

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
# All stuff related to credentials are correct
room_name = 'CoolTeam'
room = client.video.rooms(room_name).fetch()
print("room")

print(room,0)
print(room.unique_name,1)
print(room.max_participants,2)
print(room.duration,3)
room.update('completed') # I tried destroying the room
print(room.duration,4)
print(room.end_time,5)
print(room.date_created,6)
duration = room.duration
print(duration,7)
```

As I see in [their documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#rooms-list-resource), the output may be a python dictionary

This is the output

```
'room'
<Twilio.Video.V1.RoomInstance sid=CoolTeam> 0
'CoolTeam' 1
50 2
None 3
None 4
None 5
2018-08-21 21:53:43+00:00 6
None 7
```

Basically I want to get the duration of the room, before or after the room is completed

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you're doing things right here, with one exception. In the last line you are just calling `print(duration, 7)` instead of `print(room.duration, 7)` which I believe is leading to that last `None` result.

I also believe that the `duration`, like the `end_time`, will only be available once the room is completed. Which is why it is `None` in your 4th print statement.

Give that a go and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! my mistake in the *7th print* (this was a variable storing the duration). But as you said, I tried printing `print(room.duration,3)` before destroying the room, and `print(room.duration,4)` after destroying the room, and it's still `None`, only the `end_time` returns a value

Comment: Apologies, I completely missed the variable assignment on the line before ‍♂️ I'm not sure what's going on then, I'm going to look into this a bit deeper.